# Swift with Spritekit - Joystick with knob Tutorial

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, touchesmoved

Im working on an SpriteKit Tutorial with Swift these days.

I programmed Joystick with a knob, that can be moved everywhere within the joystick circle.

Heres the relevant code snippet:

```
for touch in touches {
let position = touch.location(in: joystick)

let length = sqrt(pow(position.y, 2) + pow(position.x, 2))
let angle = atan2(position.y, position.x)

if knobRadius > length {
    joystickKnob.position = position
} else {
    joystickKnob.position = CGPoint(x: cos(angle) * knobRadius, y: sin(angle) * knobRadius)
}}
```

Here is a picture from the tutorial:

[image]

But now I want to do this a little different.

I want that the Knob only can be moved on the X and Y axis like a cross - like Up, Down, Left, right on a rail.

[image]

I really do understand the code - I think its more like a math problem :)

Can somebody tell me how to move the knob within a cross on rails?

Comment: round your angle to an interval of pi/2

Comment: also, i think your if statement is wrong.  dont you want the knob to be no greater than knob radius, so you want `let radius = min(knobRadius,length);joystickKnob.position = CGPoint(x: cos(angle) * radius, y: sin(angle) * radius)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep your angle on the cross hairs, you need to round the angle to an interval of pi/2

to do that, just do:

```
angle = (angle * 2 / CGFloat.pi).rounded() * (CGFloat.pi / 2)
```

Below I have modified your code to work a lot nicer, and allows you to avoid the branching.

I am using the base radius instead of the knob radius, so that you can never exceed the base.

```
for touch in touches {
    let position = touch.location(in: joystick)

    let radius = min(baseRadius,sqrt(pow(position.y, 2) + pow(position.x, 2))
    // a nicer way to get radius
    //let radius = min(baseRadius,position.distance(to:CGPoint.zero)) 
    let angle = atan2(position.y, position.x)
    if crossHairStick
    {
        angle = (angle * 2 / CGFloat.pi).rounded() * (CGFloat.pi / 2)
    }
    joystickKnob.position = CGPoint(x: cos(angle) * radius, y: sin(angle) * radius)
}
```

If you want to keep the knob inside of the base, subtract the knob radius. (This assumes both radius are positive, otherwise use absolute value of the radius)

```
for touch in touches {
    let position = touch.location(in: joystick)

    let radius = min(baseRadius - knobRadius,sqrt(pow(position.y, 2) + pow(position.x, 2))
    let angle = atan2(position.y, position.x)
    if crossHairStick
    {
        angle = (angle * 2 / CGFloat.pi).rounded() * (CGFloat.pi / 2)
    }
    joystickKnob.position = CGPoint(x: cos(angle) * radius, y: sin(angle) * radius)
}
```

Comment: You are amazing - Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

So you want to constrain `angle` to be a multiple of `.pi / 2` (90 degrees). The `atan2` function returns a value in the range `-.pi ... +.pi`. Convert it from radians to units of quarter-turns (right angles), round to an integer, then convert back to radians.

```
let touchAngle = atan2(position.y, position.x) // -.pi ... +.pi
let quarterTurns = touchAngle * 2 / .pi // -2 ... +2
let integralQuarterTurns = quarterTurns.rounded() // -2, -1, 0, +1, or +2
let angle = integralQuarters * .pi / 2
```

Alternatively, look at which of `abs(position.x)` and `abs(position.y)` is larger, and use that to determine `angle`:

```
let angle: CGFloat
switch abs(position.x) > abs(position.y) {
case true where position.x > 0: angle = 0
case true where position.x < 0: angle = .pi
case false where position.y > 0: angle = .pi / 2
case false where position.y < 0: angle = .pi / -2
default: angle = 0 // position == .zero so joystick is actually centered
}
```

Comment: You are amazing - Thank You!